# Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, node-modules

Basically, I am using javascript to scrape data from Google Play store using:

1-Request

2-Cheerios

3-QueryString

I used Google Market API from Github which uses require as following:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var qs = require('querystring');
```

But I am getting the following

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined ...
```

So, I don't have to `require()` in javascript which is either new for me or this is something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Please provide a link to the library you are using.

Comment: Does this question pertain to Node or the browser? It's unclear other than the node-modules tag. If browser, the canonical is [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will
>   improve the speed and quality of your code.
>
> ```
> IE 6+ .......... compatible ✔
> Firefox 2+ ..... compatible ✔
> Safari 3.2+ .... compatible ✔
> Chrome 3+ ...... compatible ✔
> Opera 10+ ...... compatible ✔
> ```

http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html

Add this to your project: https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js

and take a look at this http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: I added this script and still get "require is not defined".

Answer (score 48):

By default `require()` is not a valid function in client side javascript. I recommend you look into [require.js](http://requirejs.org) as this does extend the client side to provide you with that function.

Answer (score 13):

Require (https://requirejs.org/) is an AMD API . I had a similar issue while implementing monaco-editor in my application. This script tag helped me:

```
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: By the way to use monaco editor you don't need the require tag since currently it is there in the monaco cdn itself

Answer (score 8):

Yes, require is a Node.JS function and doesn't work in client side scripting without certain requirements. If you're getting this error while writing electronJS code, try the following:

In your BrowserWindow declaration, add the following webPreferences field:
i.e, instead of plain `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()`, write

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: still getting same issue

Comment: IN which place i need to write this code ? mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

Answer (score 4):

Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

Use the following command to install browserify

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Now recursively bundle up all the required modules like main.js into a single file called bundle.js with the browserify command:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Drop a single  tag into your html and you're done!

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

For more details click here https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify and https://browserify.org/#install

Comment: it says The term 'browserify' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet when doing "browserify main.js -o bundle.js"

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was I did not have my webpack build mode set to production for the package I was referencing in. Explicitly setting it to    "build": "webpack --mode production" fixed the issue.