# how to use Highcharts on Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, highcharts

I did not understand how to use Highcharts on Ionic.

- Ionic version 3.4.0
- Highcharts version 5.0.12

Following the Highcharts guide for [installation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm), include in my file.ts

```
import highchart from 'highcharts/highcharts.js';

var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

Then Ionic sever gives me the error

> Cannot find name 'require'

Comment: You need to run the script i.e in nodejs server. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined. In the ionic you can use regular reference to Highcharts by <script src=""> and init: http://jsfiddle.net/888dhk2d/

Comment: i installed **requiredjs** by cli with the command `npm install requiredjs --save`, but I always have the same mistake. I would to implement highchart in js and not in jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this at the top:

```js
declare var require: any;
```

In general I suggest you install `highcharts` module instead of using npm install `angular2-highcharts`:

```
$ npm install highcharts --save
```

Then you can declare Highcharts like this:

```js
declare var require: any;
let hcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(hcharts);
```

Here's a full example:

```js
import { ElementRef, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic/angular';

declare var require: any;
let hcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(hcharts);


@Component({
    selector: 'page-about',
    template: `<div #myChart></div>`,
})
export class AboutPage {
    @ViewChild('myChart') canvas: ElementRef;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        let chart = hcharts.chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        let self = this;
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            self.reflow();
                        }, 100);
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
            }],
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your snippet above and now i have not  **require** error. But tells  me now `TypeError: Can not read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`. Sorry but I did not understand, should I do the same thing you do on the plunker link? @maninak

Comment: `ElementRef` needs to be included from `@angular/core`

Comment: If you are following the code in the image, you'll also need a `<canvas #myChart style="width:100%; height:400px;"></canvas>` in the html template.

Comment: In fact I did it, only I can not solve the previous mistake

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: I added **ElementRef** in the import. But I always get this mistake at runtime `TypeError: Can not read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

Comment: It will be undefined if the elementRef cannot find the specified element in the template to refer to. Look in my responses above, I have already answered this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564009/how-to-use-highcharts-on-ionic/44566740?noredirect=1#comment76127054_44566740

Comment: ah okay, but my code seems right to me. I did it in _file.html_ `<div class="slideshow">
  <ion-slides pager>
   <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
     <ion-card-content>
      <canvas id="graph"> ...` and in _file.ts_ `@ViewChild('graph') canvas: ElementRef;`

Comment: You have an error. In order for `@ViewChild` to find the element from your template you need to use the `#` prefix, not `id=`. So you need to change it to `<canvas #graph>`

Comment: In fact you are right, making this change does not make me anymore that mistake. But I can not see the chart.

Comment: Try to change from <canvas #graph> into `<div #graph></div`

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted but can't upvote since I don't have enough rep. I can't share the code sadly.