# Uncaught Reference : require is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angular

I am trying to make an app in ruby and angular. While I am trying to create my controller and defining the new module i get this error in console :
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I am using Cloud9 online IDE and when I define the module

> var app = angular.module('angularExample');

It says that angular is not defined.
Angular is here:

> myapp/app/assets/javascripts/angular

While the controller is here:

> myapp/app/assets/javascripts/invoices/InvoiceCtrl.js

Application.js content:

```
//= require angular
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: Tag [tag:angular] is for Angular 2+, the tag [tag:angularjs] is for angular 1.x, please remove the incorrect tag :)

Comment: @0mpurdy that does not work :"couldn't find file 'angularjs' with type 'application/javascript'"

Comment: @FlavFlavius Sorry, I was referring to the tags in your Stack Overflow question - not the code that is causing the problem