# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at typeahead.js:2

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am getting following Error as I used Ui.bootstrap's typeahead library

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at typeahead.js:2
```

Tried googling for this but nothing helpful found,Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put our code ?

Comment: @Sudhir its library typeahead.js in which I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Require doesn't work in browser.Basically require is a node_module by which we can access other modules or files.So please if you are using it on browser side then try other things like import or self.import.

[Please refer this stack question and answer by **Latheesan**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Please also check require.js as well.
 [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)