# document.getElementById innerHTML doesn't work after require

Tags: require, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Hello I'm trying getElementById to change text inside my html web page. below you can find my 1st attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Use JavaScript to Change Text</h2>
<p>This example writes "Hello JavaScript!" into an HTML element with id="demo":</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var net     = require('net');
    var sleep   = require('sleep');
    var element = document.getElementById("demo");
    element.innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```

This code doesn't work because I can see the:

Use JavaScript to Change Text

This example writes "Hello JavaScript!" into an HTML element with id="demo":

but the:
    "Hello JavaScript!"
is missing.

Changing the positions of the vars at the beginning of the js script makes the code working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Use JavaScript to Change Text</h2>
<p>This example writes "Hello JavaScript!" into an HTML element with id="demo":</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("demo");
    element.innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    var net     = require('net');
    var sleep   = require('sleep');
</script>
```

Why? I need both sleep and net later on when I'll write other parts of the code but I need to manipulate again the "demo" html as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with both lines. The require() function is not a client side function, recognized by the browser. Typically require() is used in server side NodeJS code, but there is a require.js library file that you can add...

```
var net     = require('net');
var sleep   = require('sleep');
```

Add this to your project: 
 [http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js](http://%20http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js)

And take a look at this :
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Source :
[Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: As I've written above I've found the problem was exactly in the lines yo've found too. Probably I'm making some mistakes. I've a verys simple js code: called test.js including two lines: var net = require('net'); var sleep = require('sleep'); The code run withou problems if launched with node test.js. If I put that code inside my html code it yelds problems. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the lines with

```
var net     = require('net');
var sleep   = require('sleep');
```

are actually causing an error, which in turn causes the JS to stop evaluating, so that it doesn't hit the `getElementById` line. You can check this in you browser's developer tools, in the console.

Comment: Ok, using the brwser's developer tools I can see the error:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
But I think that's strange beacause I've written the following code inside a test.js:
    var net = require('net');
    var sleep = require('sleep');
and it works when i run it with:
    node test.js

Comment: I don't do much node, but I think that `require` is specific to node, it's not an API that is supported by browsers (one of those things that make it hard to like Javascript, for me). You could have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import or have a look at a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), one of the many tools in the JS ecosystem that you can use to load dependencies in a browser.

Comment: RequireJS is one of those many tools (as referenced by @Laurent Mouchart )