# Error DataTable is not a function in Electron

Tags: jquery, datatables, electron

I'm new to Electron and currently playing with the electron-api-demos. I'm trying to use the plug-in Datatables.net (and by my searches, I'm not the first one struggling!), both packages has been installed as dependencies (I can see them in package.json)

I had some difficulties with jQuery but after a few searches, manage to make it work using this line on the page I want it:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery')</script>
```

Then I tried many ways to add the Datatables plugin but always ending up with errors. Currently, it's a line after the one with jQuery, then the custom script:

```
<script>require('./node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables')</script>
<script>require('./renderer-process/foo/bar')</script>
```

In the custom script, I'm trying to transform a table in datatable:

```
$(function () {
  $('#datatable-bar').DataTable();
});
```

I end up with one warning and one error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I checked questions here on Stack Overflow, on the forum of Datatables.net and other websites. Two basics answer are:

- jQuery is loaded after the plug-in (not my case I reckon)
- jQuery is loaded
  twice (how could I verify that possibility?)

Help and/or any other suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, shame on me, I should have just read the documentation more thoroughly. I had to post a question here (after half a day of research) to find the right answer! But it might help others as I stumbled on the same kind of problem on a lot of different forum.

So if you check the README file of the datatables.net package, you've got the answer:

```
<script>
  var $ = require( 'jquery' );
  require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );
</script>
```

Is the way of making the plug-in works without any more errors or lines to call them as I have see on some answers. It's loading jQuery and the Datatables script. It's working like a charm now!

I reckon that page can be useful too: https://datatables.net/download/npm

Comment: I did this, and am getting this error: 
    Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Any idea on what i can do?

Comment: I'm not sure but this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined
Because your error is with the function require().