# How to solve require is not defined?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/manoharkhadka1/laravel-chat-app) to create a chat app with [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) and [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

I get *require is not defined* error in `app.js:8`.I tried so many things but  but nothing seems to solve this problem.

I tried using requirejs so i added these two line in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="{{ url('resources/assets/js/app.js')}}" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url('resources/assets/js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

and this is my app.js code:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: 'js/lib',
paths: {
    app: '../app'
}
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'],
 function   ($,        canvas,   sub) {
});
// this line below is causing the problem
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(require('vue-chat-scroll'));

Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-log', require('./components/ChatLog.vue'));
Vue.component('user-log', require('./components/UserLog.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-composer', require('./components/ChatComposer.vue'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please post a minimal version of your code as we are not magicians and have absolotely no clue of what is on line 8.

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i just updated my question to include the line that causing the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be referencing `resources/assets/js/app.js` directly. `require` is used by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which is a tool that will bundle your js assets into a single file.

Instead you should run `npm run development` and then reference `js/app.js` like [here](https://github.com/manoharkhadka1/laravel-chat-app/blob/master/resources/views/home.blade.php#L168)

See [laravel mix docs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/workflow)

Comment: so the scripts in my view should be like this:<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/app.js" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> ?

Comment: You can remove the requirejs one. See here for a more detailed example: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/3.0/workflow

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add this to your project : https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js

There is a similar issue for your problem right there : [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: i just updated my question to show the code of my app.js where the error is how should i change that file when now working with requirejs ?