# Vue.js dynamic image src with require is not defined error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to bind image src dynamically to a url in a v-for loop as below :

```
<script>
export default {    
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            games: [
                {"gameId": 1365, "gameLabel": "ssbu"},
                {"gameId": 1366, "gameLabel": "ggs"},
                {"gameId": 1367, "gameLabel": "sf5"},
            ]
        }
    }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="game in games"">
    <img :src="`../assets/cards/${game.gameLabel}.jpg`" :alt="game.gameLabel">
  </div>
</template>
```

But I had the error `GET http://localhost:3000/assets/cards/ssbu.jpg 404 (Not Found)` although it works fine when I do this : `<img src="../assets/cards/ssbu.jpg" :alt="game.gameLabel">`.

So i tried using require function as people mentionned in other posts with something like this : `` <img :src="require(`../assets/cards/${game.gameLabel}.jpg`)" :alt="game.gameLabel"> `` but there I faced the fatal error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

SO I'm stuck at this point and I need your help in order to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve require is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667055/how-to-solve-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: I dont know, I dont understand what I need to add and where and I do not use laravel either.

Comment: Looks like there is a workaround to achieve this by adding your image files to public folder instead of assets. Can you please give a try and check ?

Comment: This workaround is working, thank you. But what is the downside of putting img in public and for what work the folder is usually used ? Like what are the guidelines in using this folder ?

Comment: If using `vite`, you can use cdn for your files or importing them in your `vue` script. But if using `webpack`, you have to use `require('...')` on dynamic sources.
[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135980/15896638)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put your images into the static folder.
2. rename to:

Now you have a `cards` folder inside the static folder