# Javascript ISReachable is not working. Says require is not defined

Tags: javascript, web

```
const PREFIX = "10.100.";
const MACHINES =    ["11.1","11.2","11.3","21.1","21.2","21.3","31.1","31.2","31.3","41.1","41.2","41.3","51.1","51.2","51.3"];
const isReachable = require('is-reachable');
for (const item of MACHINES) {
    const IP = PREFIX + item;
    if (!(await isReachable(IP))) {
        warn("Unable to reach " + IP);
        continue;
    }
}
```

This is the code i currently have for a javascript program i am trying to use IsReachable as said [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-reachable)  but the program keeps saying require is not recognised. Am i missing a certain import? i have installed everythin specified in the above URL. Thx for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: .....[the browser (with a bundler)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-reachable/v/3.0.0) You missed some dependencies

Comment: @gaetanoM which dependancies am i missing? how do i find out which ones i am missing

Comment: Looks like you're running it directly in the browser. Or are you using any tools? How does the directory structure look like?