# Require doesn't work in nodejs: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am new to Javascript and started to make desktop apps with the help of nodejs and electron. The problem is that I can not use require() outside of my main.js file. But this is shown in some Tutorials I found online.

I searched for hours if I could find a solution, but I could not. I tried to reinstall nodejs, electron and the requirejs module.

```html
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>Enter Item</label>
        <input type="text" id="item" autofocus>
      </div>
      <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" type="submit">Add Item</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    //should give back the item, so that it can be added to the shoppinglist in the main window
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
      console.log(ipcRenderer);
      ipcRenderer.send('item:add', item);
    }
  </script>
```

Expected: When pressing the "Add item" button the entered item should appear in mainWindow

Actual: Nothing happens when pressing the button (Console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/10706585

Comment: The questions which you declaring as a duplicate have nothing to do with electron. The OP is asking for an electron application where you CAN use require in your JS-Code

Comment: For me the Solution was: To add Node Modules to HtmlWebpackPlugin but I'm not a pro with electron so I can just give you hints and not a complete answer.

Comment: My HtmlWebpackPlugin Config: new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.ejs'),
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeComments: true
            },
            nodeModules: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
                ? path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
                : false
        }),