# Firebase Admin SDK configuration in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication, node-modules

I want to use Firebase Admin SDK to generate Firebase auth tokens, when i set Admin SDK configuration in my js file, the following error appears (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined)

How i can require firebase-admin and serviceAccountKey json file in my js file

the project was developed using laravel framework.

I tried to use REQUIREJS API to require service account kye , but the following error appear >> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
var admin = require(['firebase-admin']);

var serviceAccount = require("{{ asset('/serviceAccountKey.json') }}");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: ""
});
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 0):

You might have a typo, try to remove the square brackets:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

or try:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

also make sure you added the the package.json with firebase-amin in it

> If you don't already have a package.json file, create one via npm
>   init. Next, install the firebase-admin npm package and save it to your
>   package.json:

if you don't have it create one using the command

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Comment: I use typescript with Firebase Functions and this works for me:

import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

Answer (score 0):

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const config = require('../config');
const catchError = require('http-errors');

const serviceAccount = require(config.FIREBASE_KEY);
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: config.FIREBASE_DB
});
```

install the firebase-admin dependencies with `npm install --save firebase-admin`

### edit

the config file contains everything related to the firebase configurations hence you can `gitignore` it easily

### Edit

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23603514/8437740) link that may be helpful and may not be related to anything on firebase.

Comment: the same result >> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: did you exported the config settings in the config file?

Comment: the idea is that require function is not defined !!

Comment: I have updated my answer that includes a link to a SO question. That will be helpful I guess