# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript

I tried to `fetch` to get some data. I want to run in `chrome` browser.

When I try to fetch to reach out such data,I suffered error like

`require is not defined`

I found question below and I trying to use`script` tag,

[Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

But I couldn't find out what kind of file should be loaded.

If someone know `script`tag solution, please let me know.

Thanks

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";

fetch(apikey)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    // console.log(json);
    console.log(json.results[0].question);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don´t need to import fetch, its part of JS.

```js
var apikey="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10";

fetch(apikey)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    // console.log(json);
    console.log(json.results[0].question);
  });
```

Comment: When I try to remove `require` I caught `fetch is not defined`. is it depend on environment?

Comment: If you want to run in browser its ok,  see the ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

Require is basically not defined,and it is a part of async function, give a read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) and make sure it is compatible with your version.

Answer (score 0):

fetch is supported by default at client side. You don’t need to require it and also require doesn’t work at client side without browserified js. You can remove the require statement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that JavaScript runs in multiple environments. There are different module systems for each environment. Commonjs is the module system with  require and module.exports, this is used in the  node.js runtime. In the browser you won’t see support for commonjs. Instead you’ll see a few different approaches to loading code.

Read more about all of the different module systems in the JS ecosystem here https://tylermcginnis.com/javascript-modules-iifes-commonjs-esmodules/.