# Require is not defined - Electron

Tags: electron

I want to use loki js and I'm trying to call it on that variable, but it appears that the require has not been defined

[image]

My package.json

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron require() is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

There in main.js, I added this line

```
nodeIntegration: true
```

inside the function that creates a window

```
function createWindow () {
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    nodeIntegration: true, //add this line
  }
})
```