# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require problem

Tags: javascript, axios

```
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
```

i have problem with gettin data. how can I fix this?

Comment: `require` is used in Node but `import` is used in the browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined. Possible duplicate if that one, please check the answers on that question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to import axios library

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: when I delete the code I can get the data. but I don't know it's okay

Comment: In that xase you should have import axios somewhere. if axios.get (for sample) is available so you should have a working project

Comment: Just in case someone else asks, you can also do something like `window.axios = import('axios')`, especially useful for `lodash`, `bootstrap`, and other packages that are imported this way.