# Error while using add ons simple ruler on ckeditor4

Tags: ckeditor, codeigniter-4, ckeditor4.x

I want to use add ons [simple ruler](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/simple-ruler) on ckeditor4 in my Codeigniter4 project. But I receive this kind of error. Already tried to browsing the solution in internet but I can't found the solution.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at ckeditor.js:1335:234
at ckeditor.js:1339:3160

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
at Object.loadPart (ckeditor.js:568:143)
at l (ckeditor.js:279:29)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:278:394)
at a.r (ckeditor.js:10:246)
at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12:91)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13:286)
at a.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:12:251)
at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13:442)
at k (ckeditor.js:276:322)
at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:276:442)
```

The code from error require is not defined ckeditor.js:1335 is

```
window.noUiSlider=require("nouislider");window.$||(window.$=require("jquery"));
```

And code from error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split') ckeditor.js:568 is

```
split(",")[0]?CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl(a()+"skin.js"),function(){b(c,d)}):b(c,d)},getPath:function(a){return CKEDITOR.getUrl(d(a))},icons:{},addIcon:function(a,b,c,d){a=a.toLowerCase();this.icons[a]||(this.icons[a]={path:b,offset:c||0,bgsize:d||"16px"})},getIconStyle:function(a,b,c,d,e){var f;a&&(a=a.toLowerCase(),b&&(f=this.icons[a+"-rtl"]),
```

I confused because I'm using the feature CKEditor4 builder online and while using those add ons, always error. But if I remove the add ons(simple ruler), the error is gone. I already put jquery on my assets. And I dont know why this error happen. Are anyone have the solution of this? Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the `require.js` library dependency **before** the `ckeditor` library and the `simple-ruler` addon. I.e: `<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript require() function giving ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa It's not answer my question, I already tried adding that but still the CKEditor not showing.